# Compute the square root of 3 in C++

Tags: c++

How can I compute the square root of 3 in C++ using the following relation?

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main(void)
{
    double prevRes(1);
    double res(1 + 1./2);
    short i(2);


    while (abs(prevRes - res) > 1.e-14)
    {
        prevRes = res;

        res = i + 1 / res;

        i = 3 - i;
    }

    std::cout << res << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs forever.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Didn't you just post this very same question (that you then deleted)? Please don't do that. You should have edited your original question to improve it instead. Now you have to edit this one instead, to explain what the problem with your attempt is. Do you get build errors? Unexpected results? Something else? What is the expected and actual output? Have you tried [to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: The program doesn't run forever. It terminates immediately with an output of `1.5`.

Comment: A solution to this relation requires a recursive method, since the term under the division in the first level depends on the answer to the second level, which in turn depends on the answer to the third level, and so on...

Comment: The problem then is that you don't know when the recursion should stop, because you can't easily tell (because of the division) what contribution each level of the calculation is making to the final result.

Comment: Why was the question down voted?

Comment: The comments tend to explain the reasons why it might have been downvoted. Note that those posting the comments are not necessarily the ones downvoting. The question started out by asking how to do something in general (how do i compute this?) rather than asking something specific (why does the program run forever?). Also, questions that could be solved with simple debugging tend to be downvoted.  That said, asking for debugging help with a clear problem statement is still on topic, but any question might be downvoted for lack of (perceived) effort. Please don't take the votes personally.

Comment: @wally, I do not take them personally. it is just that I can not ask on the SO anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shame that this question wasn't asked with more effort and detail so that it was taken seriously.  I've always been confused by the appearance and concept of continued fractions, but it's been nice taking the time to think about them and implement one.

This particular one can be done iteratively.  As @wally states, the continued fraction shown in the question does not converge to sqrt(3), but to ~1.36603.  The two top-most coefficients should be 1.  Notice that sqrt(3) ~= 1 + (1/1.36603), and that all the coefficients in the continued fraction alternate.

So, if a loop works from the bottom up until the alternating continued fraction converges then one more calculation after the loop will give us the correct answer.  At each iteration the reciprocal of the current value is added to either 1 or 2.  The initial value can be anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

// Calculate square root of 3 with a continued fraction
int main(void) {
  int iterations = 0;
  double epsilon = 1.0e-12; //error bounds
  double prev = 0.0;
  double curr = 1.0; //initial estimate
  double error = curr - prev;

  // Don't show more precision than we have
  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);

  // Iterate the continued fraction [1;1,2,1,2...]
  // from the bottom up until it converges with errors
  // less than epsilon.
  while (std::abs(error) > epsilon) {
    prev = curr;
    // Unroll the loop with the repeating pattern here
    curr = 2 + (1/curr);
    curr = 1 + (1/curr);

    iterations++;
    error = curr - prev;
    std::cout << "error at iteration " << iterations
              << " was " << error << std::endl;
  }

  // The actual continued fraction we want to evaluate
  // is [1;1,1,2,1,2,...].
  // The two top-level coefficients are 1, so do
  // another half iteration here. 
  curr = 1 + (1/curr);

  std::cout << "sqrt(3) = " << curr << " after "
            << iterations << " iterations" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This strategy should work for any continued fraction with that ends in a repeating pattern of coefficients.

As for why the original code does not complete, I'll leave that to the author to figure out.  Print statements or a pocket calculator will help.

Answer (score 2):

The formula seems a bit wrong if I compare it to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_3). Note the 1 + is repeated at the start.

Next we can use a recursive function to perform the calculation and provide a number of iterations. Note that we can use a large return value to terminate the recursion (or even zero, but that would require more iterations as it is technically making the wrong assumption).

Finally we keep trying more iterations until the error is small enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

double f(int depth, bool odd = true)
{
    if(depth == 0)
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    return (odd ? 1 : 2) + 1. / f(--depth, !odd);
}

double sqrt3(int depth = 10)
{
    return 1 + 1. / f(depth);
}

int main(void)
{
    int depth{2};
    double prevRes{sqrt3(depth)};
    double res{sqrt3(++depth)};
    while(abs(prevRes - res) > 1.e-14)
    {
        prevRes = res;
        res = sqrt3(++depth);
    }

    std::cout << "Answer is " << res << " at depth " << depth << ".\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Answer is 1.73205 at depth 26.
```

Comment: It seems weird that you can return any value in the base case. Maths...

Answer (score 1):

```
double sqrt_of_three(bool adds_two, int rec_depth, int max_rec_depth)
{
    int x;
    if (rec_depth < 2)
        x =  1;
    else 
        x = adds_two ? 2 : 1;
    if (rec_depth < max_rec_depth)
        return x + 1/sqrt_of_three(!adds_two, ++rec_depth, max_rec_depth);
    return x;
}
```

And this method can be called with an estimate for a threshold.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << sqrt_of_three(true, 0, 10);
}
```

This is an example how to recursively call a function that calculates the square root of 3. Now you can either manually set the maximum recursion depth by trial and error or you do something that you did with your first approach and check after each complete recursion if the value between two different maximum recursion depths is smaller than some threshold.

It's for sure not the most efficient way to find the square root of three because you have to do `n*(n-1)/2` (where `n` is the recursion depth that satisfied the boundary that you set) recursions in total and depending on how close you want to converge to the real result this can be a lot.

Comment: Don't use recursion for things like this. Please.

Comment: @RustyX How would you do it using the continuous fraction relation?

Comment: @Philipp See my answer for an iterative implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in sqrt function.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
    double param, result;
    param = 1024.0;
    result = sqrt (param);
    printf ("sqrt(%f) = %f\n", param, result );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question asks about solving the problem with the given formula, not with buildin functions.

Comment: @Nova Where does it say that? All I see is, "How can I compute the square root of 3 in C++ using the following relation", which the built in function fulfills. For people Googling "sqrt C++", we absolutely do not want someone to come up with an answer that reinvents the wheel. If it is an academic exercise, with academic requirements, the OP needs to explicitly state those requirements. i.e. "This is an academic execise" and "I am not allowed to use built the built in function for this academic exercise" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Mentioning the following relation would be useless if the buildin function was enough. Why stating that when you don't really care how the root was calculated? Yes, I understand the question as academic exercise - or homework. Yes, your answer would be the best for someone googling "sqrt C++", but I believe no one will see this question after googling that.

Comment: He's obviously someone just starting, so he might not even know it exists. My answer reflects the question as it is stated. As do all my answers. I do not read between the lines. I am a programmer. I deal with logic. Currently it is the 4th hit in the following search:  
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS774&ei=F9omWvDxPMewjwOl24jQDQ&q=C%2B%2B+compute+the+square+root+of&oq=C%2B%2B+compute+the+square+root+of&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l2.6775.6775.0.7046.1.1.0.0.0.0.136.136.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.136....0.TSsZN08kOxw 
Do you want to argue? IM me for further arguments.